# Are DOM commands ignored when treating a function as a value?

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I'm fairly new to JS and programming in general. I'm teaching myself casually and just for fun! Take a look at this:

```
var a=0;
var b=0;

function test(){
  a++;
  b++;
  document.body.innerHTML+=a+" "+b;
  return 42;
}

$("document").ready(function(){
  test();
});
```

This (as expected) prints out

```
1 1
```

And the return value seems meaningless when you're just running the function. If, on the other hand, I modify it so that it reads...

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  document.body.innerHTML+=test()+" "+a+" "+b;
});
```

This prints out:

```
42 1 1
```

This means that 'var a' got incremented and 'var b' got incremented and the 42 was returned as the value of test() but the DOM part of test() was ignored.
Why is this? Is anything else ignored?
Thanks.

Comment: Oh thank goodness - so nothing is being ignored hah.
Yes - I replaced the first instance of doc.body.inner to the inner of a div element and did the same with the second instance in test() with another div element and yes. All the code is run :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really comes down to what does `+=` mean?

```
x += y;
// same as
x = x + y;
```

So

```
document.body.innerHTML += test() + " " + a + " " + b;
// same as 
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + test() + " " + a + " " + b;
//               X                         Y
```

Now you can see, the `document.body.innerHTML` *Y* is being taken **before** it is changed by `test()`, so the changes made in `test` are not in *Y*.

Comment: In other words the operation on body made in test() is being written over in the document ready callback?

Comment: @STT Yes, the changes from `test` are made, but then immediately undone when the _HTML_ gets set the second time, because it's using a copy from before the changes were made.